# HTML5 Footer being pushed off screen to the left

Tags: css

[image: The code and it's output]

[image: The code and it's output]

CSS

```
html {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* -- Header Styles --*/
header {
  background: #000
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #DDD;
}

/* -- Navigation Styles  -- */
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #111;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #AAA;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* -- Body Styles -- */
article {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 3px;
}

#ogpost {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  clear: both;
}

/* -- Footer Styles -- */
footer {
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  background: #222;
}

footer h1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

footer article {
  width: 10%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: none;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DDD;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#cpyrt {
  clear: both;
  background: #010101;
  color: #666;
}

#cpyrt ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Dungeon Dudes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>Dungeon Dudes</h1>

      <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Homebrew</a>
        <a href="#">Campaign</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <article id="ogpost">
      <h3>The Site is Running!</h3>

      <p>We are very pleased to announce that Dungeon Dudes is now up and running! Here we will show you various content ranging everywhere from video games to table top games. Our main focus is Dungeons and Dragons but some of us will play wit hother systems and share content about those as well. We will post articles about games, game mechanics, how tos, anything and everything related to games.</p>

      <a href="#">Read more...</a>
    </article>

    <footer>
      <h1>Dungeon<br>Dudes</h1>

      <article>
        <h6>Quick Links</h6>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h6>Support</h6>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h6>Follow Us</h6>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>
      </article>

      <article id="cpyrt">
        <p>&copy 2018 Dungeon Dudes | All Rights Reserved</p>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Above I have two image my code that I've attempted and it's output. I'm very confused as to why this is happening. I want the copyright section of my footer to be equal to the width of the footer. but if I try to set the width it gets cutoff on the left side. I've had things get cut off on the right and I know how to deal with that but I've never had it happen the other way.

Comment: Not clear without some coding, try please to add your code so that we can understand what you want.

Comment: Without including the HTML structure or other CSS that's affecting it, there's really no way to answer this. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51863961/edit) your question to include the code in question into the question itself, not just images of code.

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#cpyrt` element would need the following styles to go full width like you want:

```
#cpyrt {
    clear: both;
    background: #010101;
    color: #666;

    /*new styles*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Right now all your elements have the default `box-sizing: content-box;` which does not include paddings and borders into with `%` calculations. And margins will never get added also. So your `width: 100%` was actually 100% + 10px padding left + 10px padding right + 10px margin left + 10px margin right... thus why it was to big. So set the box-sizing and remove both left and right margins.

```css
html {
    background: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* -- Header Styles --*/

header {
    background: #000
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #DDD;
}

/* -- Navigation Styles  -- */

nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #111;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AAA;
    margin: 10px;
}

/* -- Body Styles -- */

article {
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 3px;
}

#ogpost {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    clear: both;
}

/* -- Footer Styles -- */

footer {
    overflow: auto;
    clear: both;
    background: #222;
}

footer h1 {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

footer article {
    width: 10%;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: none;
}

footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DDD;
}

footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#cpyrt {
    clear: both;
    background: #010101;
    color: #666;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#cpyrt ul {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Dungeon Dudes</h1>

    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Homebrew</a>
        <a href="#">Campaign</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>

<article id="ogpost">
    <h3>The Site is Running!</h3>

    <p>We are very pleased to announce that Dungeon Dudes is now up and running! Here we will show you various content ranging everywhere from video games to table top games. Our main focus is Dungeons and Dragons but some of us will play wit hother systems
        and share content about those as well. We will post articles about games, game mechanics, how tos, anything and everything related to games.</p>

    <a href="#">Read more...</a>
</article>

<footer>
    <h1>Dungeon<br>Dudes</h1>

    <article>
        <h6>Quick Links</h6>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h6>Support</h6>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h6>Follow Us</h6>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>
    </article>

    <article id="cpyrt">
        <p>&copy 2018 Dungeon Dudes | All Rights Reserved</p>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</footer>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I've never heard of the box-sizing property so I never would've figured that out on my own.

Comment: @user10230670 typically this style will be set globally for all elements (not individually per element) since it is the preferred method of size calculation. This is done in a lot of css resets and frameworks (like Bootstrap) stylesheets like this: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` where the `*` targets every element on the page. Just be warned if you do that now it might mess up your layout since you already styled for `content-box`.